# Programmatically set a semantic ui search field and automatically select the first response

Tags: semantic-ui

I am inserting values into a web page somewhat like an automated test environment.

A valid value is set on a search input text field. Normally the user types a code and the selection list shows the code and the description. When the user selects a value there is additional processing that happens.

After the value is set onto the field I would like it to automatically select the first entry (because there will be only one).

As of 2.2 I know there is a selectFirstResult option for the search fields. However, I don't want to set that as a permanent setting in the page, I just need it for this operation. Is it possible to set just that flag once the page is fully loaded and after the field has already been initialized as a search? When I attempted to do it I lost all the original search settings for that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify existing settings of a search (or any component), you can use the `setting` property which will not discard your original search settings.

```
// To enable selectFirstResult
$('.ui.search').search('setting', { selectFirstResult: true });

// To disable selectFirstResult
$('.ui.search').search('setting', { selectFirstResult: false });
```